# Subscribing to event of multiple instances of a class

Tags: c#, algorithm, events

I have a program with a custom Shape class as follows

```
class Shape
{
public:
Event<ShapeArgs> shapeBurst;
virtual void onMousePress(); //inside this, shapeBurst event is notifed
};
```

There are 15 instances of the Shape class in my program. I have to subscribe to the event for all these instances and provide a common handler. However, I have a doubt here about how to subscribe to the event from all the 15 classes.
Should I actually write down each instance in the form below subscribe to the shapeBurst method or is there a better method to do so?

```
shape.shapeBurst += new ShapeBurstEventHandler(ShapeBurstMethod);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have 15 shape object then your can use array of objects instead of 15 variables and use loop to subscribe to event.

```
for(int i=0; i < shape.Length;i++)
  shape[i].shapeBurst += new ShapeBurstEventHandler(ShapeBurstMethod);
```